# Can't access phpMyAdmin. My wampserver version is 2.2 localhost/phpmyadmin/

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

Can't access phpMyAdmin. My wampserver version is 2.2 using windows 7.

```
localhost/phpmyadmin/
```

when i open it. Internet explorer opens and give web page cannot be found.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Left click the wampmanager icon to reveal the `menu-> Apache -> Service`
If the Start resume service menu item is Green then Apache is running.

Left click the wampmanager icon to reveal the `menu-> MySQL -> Service`
If the Start resume service menu item is Green then MySQL is running.

If Apache is the service that is not running it is normally, but not always, because something else has captured port 80.

Now do,
Left click the wampmanager icon to reveal the `menu-> Apache -> Service -> Test port 80`
This will launch a command window and display some information about what, if anything is using port 80.

Whatever it is should be re-configured to not use port 80 or uninstalled if you are not using it.

If port 80 is not the problem look for errors in the appropriate error log ( use the wamp manager menus to view the error logs )

If these do not exists or show no errors then also check the

```
Windows Event Viewer
Start -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer
```

And look in the 'Windows Logs' -> Application' section accessed from the menu on the left of the dialog for error messages from Apache and or MySQL.

```
How to Configure SKYPE so it does not require port 80 or 443
```

Run SKYPE
then using the menus do this:
Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection
Un-Check the checkbox next to 'Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incomming connections'
Now restart SKYPE for these changes to take effect.

```
How to Configure Team Viewer so it does not require port 80 or 443
```

Run TV
Extras -> Options -> Advanced -> Press the Advanced Button -> Advanced Network Connections
Check the checkbox saying [ Dont use incomming port 80 (recommended for web servers only ) ]

If the problem is not obvious then post the errors here

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change the port 80 to 81, maybe it's working.

Comment: what port and from where can u explain ? i am new to wamp

Comment: C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.8\conf\httpd.conf
Do a search for “Listen   80″and replace it with “Listen 81″.
Save and close the file.

Answer (score 0):

Skype can be a problem. Check if it's running in system tray. If it is, close it and again restart the services. Hope it works.